# Seal script translation please (Characters identified: 老伴)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

Hi, can anyone help me with this name in seal script, please? It's from a Chinese picture.

Comment: 老伴(old companion) is an intimate address for one's long-time partner, (normally, husband and wife)

Comment: Thank you. The old character is very stylized!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some screenshot from some kind of special input method.

[image: 劳]

[image: 伴]